# How to set up two-factor authentication with ASP.net Identity 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I must be missing something super simple or I'm not fully understanding how two-factor authentication is supposed to work for ASP.net Identity 2.0.

My understanding is that two-factor authentication is supposed to work like GoDaddy or Google; when you attempt to log in from a computer without a valid second factor cookie, an email or SMS is sent with an auth code and you are presented with a second form to enter your auth code in order to complete the sign in process.

All of the code appears to be present in a new MVC 5 project, except I had to implement the SendAsync function for the Email Service:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1", 25);
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("sender@domain.com", message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);
        smtpClient.Send(mail);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

However, when I log in, no email is sent and no auth code form is displayed.

I went in to the Manage View (Views => Manage => Index) and uncommented the TwoFactor section. I logged back in, went to the manage screen, and enabled two-factor authentication for the account, but it didn't make a bit of difference.

Thoughts on what am I missing?

---

**Edit**

Ok, so it appears the crux of my problem may be related to registration confirmation. The two factor authentication only appears to work when the email has been confirmed. Otherwise the code does not send. So you either need to enable the email confirmation in the Registration, or set `EmailConfirmed = true` when you register the user.

Comment: Your SMTP Server is configured correctly on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, using Smtp4Dev to listen. Can send emails using the same method in other parts of the code.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity ?

Comment: Yes, I have. unfortunately, didn't help

Comment: Is it possible to do it with email only, or does it have to have the SMS/twilio thing?

Comment: Ok, so it appears the crux of the problem may be related to registration confirmation. The two factor authentication only appears to work when the email has been confirmed. Otherwise the code does not send.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368154/how-to-make-google-authentication-scan-qr-code/47368506#47368506 something you want...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the email has to be marked as confirmed for two-factor authentication to work.